# C Reading in integers from txt without fscanf

Tags: c, function, stream, int, stdin

I'm trying to take getbits from K&R C 2.9 and pass a text file containing ints through, check to make sure getbits() can handle them, and format the ouput to another txt file. I'm stumped and my instructor told me NOT to use fscanf, use stdin and maybe scanf.

Here's my code

```
include <stdio.h>


unsigned int getbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n) 
{
  return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) &  ~(~0 << n);
}


int main()
{
  File * ipf = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  int x = 0 , p = 0, n = 0, b = 0;

  while(fscanf(ipf, "%d, %d, %u", &p, &n, &x) != EOF)
  {

    if(x < 4294967296 && p < 32 && n < p + 2)
    { 
      b = getbits(x,p,n);
      printf("gebits( x = %u, p = %d, n =  %d) = %u\n", x, p, n, b);
    } 
    else { printf("ERROR"); }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

input.txt

```
2,1,127
2,4,127
31,3,1431655765
32,3,1431655765
```

output.txt

```
getbits(x=127, p=2, n=1) = 1
ERROR
getbits(x=1431655765, p=31, n=3) = 2
ERROR
```

I know this is all basic but I really apreciate any help :)

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong, you have to think about what will happen when there is an error in the file so it has, for example, more or less values in a single line. I recommend you read e.g. [this `fscanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Also, be careful with your comparison with `4294967296`, as that literal is not an `int` but a `long long` (if your compiler have that type). Besides, `x` is of type `int` and not `unsigned int` (which you read and print it as).

Comment: As for how to read integers without using `fscanf`, you might want to read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: i think your output is as expected as per your code.So what is wrong you feel and error?. you not want to use `fscanf` because your instructor not allow it right.

Comment: If I'm on a 32bit system won't my ints be 4 bytes @JoachimPileborg?

Comment: @Lsooties Yes, `int` will be 32 bits even on most 64-bit systems. But `4294967296` is *not* a 32-bit value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right. But if I make x unsigned then would it be able to reach 4294967296?

Comment: No, it will never be able to do that, because the literal number is beyond the range of a 32-bit integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read an integer from the file without using `fscanf`. Here is some code which reads content from the file, without using `fscanf`. I also corrected some data type declaration for your value in which you compared `int` data to `long long`.

```
int main()
{
    FILE * ipf = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    long long x = 0 , p = 0, n = 0, b = 0;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *token;

      while ((read = getline(&line, &len, ipf)) != -1)
      {   
            token=strtok(line,",");
            p=atoi(token);

            token=strtok(NULL,",");
            n=atoi(token);

            token=strtok(NULL,"");
            x=atoi(token);

            if(x < 4294967296 && p < 32 && n < p + 2)
            { 
              b = getbits(x,p,n);
              printf("gebits( x = %lld, p = %lld, n =  %lld) = %lld\n", x, p, n, b);
            } 
            else { printf("ERROR\n"); }
      }

  return 0;
}
```

For Windows, use the following solution:

```
int main()
{
    FILE * ipf = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    long long x = 0 , p = 0, n = 0, b = 0;
    char line [256];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *token;

  while ((fgets(line,256, ipf)) != 0)
  {   
        token=strtok(line,",");
        p=atoi(token);

        token=strtok(NULL,",");
        n=atoi(token);

        token=strtok(NULL,"");
        x=atoi(token);

        if(x < 4294967296 && p < 32 && n < p + 2)
        { 
          b = getbits(x,p,n);
          printf("gebits( x = %lld, p = %lld, n =  %lld) = %lld\n", x, p, n, b);
        } 
        else { printf("ERROR\n"); }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `getline` is not a C standard function, and will not exist on platforms such as Windows.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes you are right,getline() is not in the C standard library, but is a POSIX 2008 extension.So it will help OP if he not use windows else may require different solution.